# Reshape documents by splitting a field value

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose we have a collection of raw data:

```
{ "person": "David, age 102"}
{ "person": "Max, age 8" }
```

and we'd like to transform that collection to:

```
{ "age": 102 }
{ "age": 8 }
```

using only mongo(d) engine. (If all person names or ages had equal lengths, $substr could do the job, ) Is it possible?

Suppose regex is trivial /\d+/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The optimal way in  MongoDB version 3.4.

This version of `mongod` provides the [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split) operator which, of course split the string as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38039035/3100115).

We then assign the the newly computed value to a variable using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) variable operator. The new value can then be use in the **in** expression to return the "name" and the "age" values using the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt) operator to return the element at a specified index; `0` for the first element and `-1` for the last element.

Note that in the **in** expression we need to split the last element in order to return the string of integer.

Finally we need to iterate the `Cursor` object and cast the convert the string of integer to numeric using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and use bulk operation and the [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method to [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) the value for those field for maximum efficiency.

```
let requests = [];
db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": {  
            "person": { 
                "$let": { 
                    "vars": { 
                        "infos":  { "$split": [ "$person", "," ] } 
                    }, 
                    "in": { 
                        "name": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$infos", 0 ] }, 
                        "age": { 
                            "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                                { "$split": [ 
                                    { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$infos", -1 ] }, 
                                    " " 
                                ]}, 
                                -1 
                            ] 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }  
        }}
    ] 
).forEach(document => { 
    requests.push({ 
        "updateOne": { 
            "filter": { "_id": document._id }, 
            "update": { 
                "$set": { 
                    "name": document.person.name, 
                    "age": Number(document.person.age) 
                },
                "$unset": { "person": " " }
            } 
        } 
    }); 
    if ( requests.length === 500 ) { 
        // Execute per 500 ops and re-init
        db.coll.bulkWrite(requests); 
        requests = []; 
    }} 
);

 // Clean up queues
if(requests.length > 0) {
    db.coll.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

---

### MongoDB 3.2 or newer.

MongoDB 3.2 deprecates the old [`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API and its associated [methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) and provides the `bulkWrite()` method but it doesn't provide the `$split` operator so the only option we have here is to use the [`mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) method to transform our data then update the collection using bulk operation.

```
var mapFunction = function() { 
    var person = {}, 
    infos = this.person.split(/[,\s]+/); 
    person["name"] = infos[0]; 
    person["age"] = infos[2]; 
    emit(this._id, person); 
};

var results = db.coll.mapReduce(
    mapFunction, 
    function(key, val) {}, 
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)["results"];

results.forEach(document => { 
    requests.push({ 
        "updateOne": { 
            "filter": { "_id": document._id }, 
            "update": { 
                "$set": { 
                    "name": document.value.name, 
                    "age": Number(document.value.age) 
                }, 
                "$unset": { "person": " " }
            } 
        } 
    }); 
    if ( requests.length === 500 ) { 
        // Execute per 500 operations and re-init
        db.coll.bulkWrite(requests); 
        requests = []; 
    }} 
);

// Clean up queues
if(requests.length > 0) {
    db.coll.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

---

### MongoDB version 2.6 or 3.0.

We need to use the now deprecated [Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).

```
var bulkOp = db.coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

results.forEach(function(document) { 
    bulkOp.find({ "_id": document._id}).updateOne(
        { 
            "$set": { 
                "name": document.value.name, 
                "age": Number(document.value.age)
            },
            "$unset": { "person": " " }
        }
    );
    count++;
    if (count === 500 ) {
        // Execute per 500 operations and re-init
        bulkOp.execute();
        bulkOp = db.coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// clean up queues
if (count > 0 ) {
    bulkOp.execute();
}
```