# Most efficient way to change a string field value to its substring

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection filled with documents that look like this:

```
{
    data: 11,
    version: "0.0.32"  
}
```

and some have a `test` suffix to `version`:

```
{
    data: 55,
    version: "0.0.42-test"  
}
```

The `version` field has different values but it always conforms to the pattern: `0.0.XXX`. I would like to update all the documents to look like this:

```
{
    data: 11,
    version: 32  
}
```

and the suffixed version (for test documents - `version` should be negative):

```
{
    data: 55,
    version: -42  
}
```

The collection with these documents is used by our critical system, that needs to be turned off while updating the data - so I want the update/change to be as fast as possible. There are about `66_000_000` documents in this collection, and it's about 100GB in size.

Which type of mongodb operation would be the most efficient one?

Comment: regarding the title, `32` is __not__ a substring of `"0.0.32"`. In fact, it's not a string at all. JFYI.

Comment: The core of the problem is taking a substring. Could you help me with finding s better title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is in the upcoming release of MongoDB as of this writing using the `$split` operator to split our string as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38039035/3100115) then assign the last element in the array to a variable using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) variable operator and the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt) operators.

Next, we use the `$switch` operator to perform a logical condition processing or case statement against that variable.

The condition here is [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) which returns true if the value contains `"test"`, and in which case in the *in* expression we split that string and simply return the [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat)enated value of the first element in the newly computed array and the `-`. If the condition evaluates to false, we just return the variable.

Of course in our case statement, we use the `$indexOfCP` which returns `-1` if there were no occurrences of `"test"`.

```
let cursor = db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "data": 1, 
            "version": { 
                "$let": { 
                    "vars": { 
                        "v": { 
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                                { "$split": [ "$version", "." ] }, 
                                -1
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    "in": { 
                        "$switch": { 
                            "branches": [ 
                                { 
                                    "case": { 
                                        "$gt": [ 
                                            { "$indexOfCP": [ "$$v", "test" ] },
                                            -1 
                                        ]
                                    }, 
                                    "then": { 
                                        "$concat": [ 
                                            "-", 
                                            "", 
                                            { "$arrayElemAt": [
                                                { "$split": [ "$$v", "-" ] }, 
                                                0 
                                            ]} 
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ], 
                            "default": "$$v" 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

The aggregation query produces something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a98773cbbd42a2156260d8"), "data" : 11, "version" : "32" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a98773cbbd42a2156260d9"), "data" : 55, "version" : "-42" }
```

As you can see, the "version" field data are string. If the data type for that field does not matter then, you can simply use the `$out` aggregation pipeline stage operator to write the result into a new collection or replace your collection.

```
{ "out": "collection" }
```

If you need to convert your data to floating point number then, the only way to do this, simply because MongoDB doesn't not provides a way to do type conversion out of the box except for integer to string, is to iterate the aggregation Cursor object and convert your value using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) then update your documents using the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator and the [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method for maximum efficiency.

```
let requests = [];
cursor.forEach(doc => { 
    requests.push({ 
        "updateOne": { 
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id }, 
            "update": { 
                "$set": { 
                    "data": doc.data, 
                    "version": parseFloat(doc.version) 
                },
                "$unset": { "person": " " }
            } 
        } 
    }); 
    if ( requests.length === 1000 ) { 
        // Execute per 1000 ops and re-init
        db.collection.bulkWrite(requests); 
        requests = []; 
    }} 
);

 // Clean up queues
if(requests.length > 0) {
    db.coll.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

---

While the aggregation query will perfectly work in MongoDB 3.4 or newer our best bet from MongoDB 3.2 backwards is [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) with the `bulkWrite()` method.

```
var results = db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() { 
        var v = this.version.split(".")[2]; 
        emit(this._id, v.indexOf("-") > -1 ? "-"+v.replace(/\D+/g, '') : v)
    }, 
    function(key, value) {}, 
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)["results"];
```

`results` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57a98773cbbd42a2156260d8"),
        "value" : "32"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57a98773cbbd42a2156260d9"),
        "value" : "-42"
    }
]
```

From here you use the previous [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to update your documents.

---

From MongoDB 2.6 to 3.0 you will need to use the now deprecated [`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) API and it associated method as show in my [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682805/3100115)