# Converting some fields in Mongo from String to Array

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents where a "tags" field was switched over from being a space separated list of tags to an array of individual tags. I want to update the previous space-separated fields to all be arrays like the new incoming data.

I'm also having problems with the $type selector because it is applying the type operation to individual array elements, which are strings. So filtering by type just returns everything.

How can I get every document that looks like the first example into the format for the second example?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("12345"),
    "tags" : "red blue green white"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54321"),
    "tags" : [
        "red",
        "orange",
        "black"
    ]
}
```

Comment: excellent question.. i tried but was not able to solve it in mongodb.. then i looked up on mongodb jira and its work in progress there.. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6773

Comment: @user641887 that jira is already closed. But it is possible to do this in MongoDB without `$split`. The only problem is performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't use the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator to filter our documents here because the type of the elements in our array is "string" and as mentioned in the documentation:

> When applied to arrays, $type matches any inner element that is of the specified BSON type. For example, when matching for $type : 'array', the document will match if the field has a nested array. It will not return results where the field itself is an array.

But fortunately MongoDB also provides the `$exists` operator which can be used here with a numeric array index.

Now how can we update those documents?

Well, from MongoDB version <= 3.2, the only option we have is [`mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) but first let look at the other alternative in the upcoming release of MongoDB.

Starting from MongoDB 3.4, we can [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) our documents and use the `$split` operator to split our string into an array of substrings.

Note that to split only those "tags" which are string, we need a logical [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond)ition processing to split only the values that are string. The condition here is [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq) which evaluate to `true` when the `$type` of the field is equal to `"string"`. By the way `$type` here is new in 3.4.

Finally we can overwrite the old collection using the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out) pipeline stage operator. **But we need to explicitly specify the inclusion of other field in the `$project` stage**.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
     [
        { "$project": { 
            "tags": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ 
                        { "$type": "$tags" }, 
                        "string"
                    ]}, 
                    { "$split": [ "$tags", " " ] }, 
                    "$tags" 
                ] 
            } 
        }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]
)
```

With `mapReduce`, we need to use the [`Array.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to emit the array of substrings in our *map function*. We also need to filter our documents using the "query" option. From there we will need to iterate the "results" array and  `$set` the new value for "tags" using bulk operations using the [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method new in 3.2 or the now deprecated [`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) if we are on 2.6 or 3.0 as shown [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682805/3100115)

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() { emit(this._id, this.tags.split(" ")); }, 
    function(key, value) {}, 
    { 
        "out": { "inline": 1 }, 
        "query": { 
            "tags.0": { "$exists": false }, 
            "tags": { "$type": 2 }
        }
    }
)['results']
```